# How to treat an output of find as a string not a refrence to a file or directory

Tags: bash, sed, find, pipe

when I run

```
find  ~/foo/bar/. -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

I get an output of all subdirectories of the given path. e.g.

```
/home/user/foo/bar/a
/home/user/foo/bar/b
...
/home/user/foo/bar/abcd
```

Now I want to use that output as a string so I added `-print` to replace some of the found results

```
find  ~/foo/bar/. -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | xargs sed 's#/home/user/foo/bar/#some_text"#g'
```

but the result wasn't as expected

> sed: read error on /home/user/foo/bar/./abc: Is a directory

obviously sed doesn't treat the piped arguments as strings my intnended e.g.

```
some_text/a
some_text/b
...
some_text/abcd
```

Comment: Remove xargs, it's creating arguments from the files. Just piping the output to sed will feed them to sed's standard input.

Comment: Note that `-print` is the default, so adding it makes no difference.

Comment: you are right man I feel stupid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the path is better done using `find`'s `-printf` option:

```
find ~/foo/bar/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf 'some_text/%P\n'
```

> **%P**     File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed.

---

To fix your `sed` version, do not use `xargs`, just pipe directly to `sed` like @choroba commented alrady.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the output to `find` directly to `sed` (no `xarg`)
`-print` is the default action, so it can be ommited
Since you want to remove the path from filename string, you can use the `-prinf` option from `find` and format it with `-printf '%P\n'` (See `man 3 printf`)

```
find  ~/foo/bar/. -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed 's#/home/user/foo/bar#some_text#g'
# or
find  ~/foo/bar/. -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%P\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `awk` to replace everyting up to the last `/` with `some_text`:

```
find ~/foo/bar/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | awk '{gsub(/^.*\//, "some_text/"); print}'
```